# Switching Apple ID on Iphone to different region to download games

Tags: iphone, itunes, apple-id

I have shared an iPhone for many years using my dad's Apple ID. I want to download some games not available in the Vietnam region, so I made an apple id in New Zealand. I have three questions regarding this topic.

1. What will happen to my contact when I switch? Will I still be able to make calls (using the same sim-card) or will I be charged international rates?
2. Will the progress of my old apps be kept? I looked up another question relating to this, and the answer was yes; I am just sure if this is also the case for changed in regions.
3. My dad uses and subscribes to Isharing, so will the payment for app stop if I sign out? I am login it through Facebook

Comment: Your title is about losing game progress but the info in your question is about being charged for calls.  Which one are you asking about?  Please see [ask] for important info on asking questions on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Nothing happens to your contacts or call making functionality. You will still be able to make calls, and this does not affect calling rates at all.

2) Yes, progress in old apps will be kept. No data on the phone is deleted.

3) No, existing App Store subscriptions will not be cancelled when you sign out.